# How do you get i18n translations into index.html file that comes with Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-cli

For example:

```
<title i18n="Title|Website Title@@websiteTitle">My super duper website</title>
```

This works fine in all the templates, but not the based index.html file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `index.html` is just a static file, not related to any component, so you cant bind properties.

Have a look in to https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title

> Since an Angular application can't be bootstrapped on the entire HTML
>   document ( tag) it is not possible to bind to the text property
>   of the HTMLTitleElement elements (representing the  tag).
>   Instead, this service can be used to set and get the current title
>   value.

UPDATE: https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title

Comment: content in .ts are not translatable through angular i18n strucuture.. 

In my case I have a "loading" content that is shown while angular is bootstraping and loading initial data. still cant find a good solution :(

Comment: @Filipiz it is if you use the (undocumented) $localize function:
`titleService.setTitle($localize\`My great website\`);`